# Calcular los días que faltan para cumpleaños SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo calcular los días que faltan para el cumpleaños de una persona en SQL.

Tomando como campo fecha de nacimiento.

---

Mi consulta va de la siguiente forma:

```
select 
  Nombres,
  Apellidos,
  DATENAME( MONTH,Empleados.fechanacimiento) AS MES, 
  DAY(Empleados.fechanacimiento) AS DIA 
from Empleados
WHERE
```

En este `WHERE` quiero seleccionar los que cumplen este mes.

Comment: Pues le restas la fecha actual al dia y mes del cumple con el año actual.. que intentaste?? que problema tuviste???

Comment: Saludos. Te falta poner el código que estas probando y que resultados te arroja para orientarte.

Comment: Te doy la respuesta completa: para calcular los días, primero debes determinar si la persona ya cumplió años este año. Si no, es la resta de la fecha del cumpleaños de este año menos la fecha de hoy, y si ya los cumplió, es la resta de la fecha del cumpleaños del próximo año menos la fecha de hoy. Un saludo.

Comment: "en este where quiero seleccionar los que cumplen este mes" no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta original.. cual es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Este problema puede dividirse en varios pasos:

## Definición

Considero que se puede mejorar la definición del problema. La redacción original dice: *"los días que faltan para cumpleaños"*. Aunque no es ambigua *per se*, añadiría las palabras *el próximo* para que quedara así: *"los días que faltan para **el próximo** cumpleaños"*.

Se puede inferir que el cumpleaños *debe* ser futuro, pues dice *"los días que faltan"*, pero no está de más agregar un poco de claridad, como ya se ha visto en otra respuesta a esta pregunta dónde el programador calcula cumpleaños ya pasados.

## ¿Cumplío años ya este año?

Con lo anterior en mente, lo primero que debemos hacer es saber si la persona ya cumplió años este año o no, Esto es necesario para saber si el próximo cumpleaños es este año o el siguiente (ya se verá por qué a la hora de calcular la fecha del próximo cumpleaños).

Podemos saber si la persona ya cumplió años este año comparando el mes y el día de la fecha de cumpleaños con la de la fecha actual. Podemos utilizar la fórmula `mes * 100 + día` para obtener un número equivalente a `mmdd` y que sea comparable con otros `mmdd`, es decir que funcionen los operadores mayor, menor, mayor o igual, etc. Así, el 4 de julio se convierte en `704` el 25 de marzo en `325` y el 14 de noviembre el `1114`.

En SQL Server, podemos valernos de las funciones:

- [`getdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) para obtener la fecha actual
- [`month()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql) para obtener el mes de una fecha
- [`day()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql) para obtener el día de una fecha

El ejemplo a continuación nos dará estos números para la fecha de hoy y la fecha de mi cumpleaños:

```
select   month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate()) mmddhoy
       , month('19750728') * 100 + day('19750728') mmddcumple
       , case 
           when month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate()) = month('19750728') * 100 + day('19750728') then 'jachguate está cumpliendo años'
           when month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate()) > month('19750728') * 100 + day('19750728') then 'jachguate ya cumplió años'
           else 'jachguate no ha cumplido años'
         end descripción
```

```
mmddhoy     mmddcumple  descripción
----------- ----------- ------------------------------
504         728         jachguate no ha cumplido años
```

## Calcular el próximo cumpleaños

Acá nos vemos limitados por las capacidades de SQL Server, dado que a un campo de tipo fecha no podemos simplemente sustituir el año, nos vemos obligados a utilizar aritmética de fechas para obtener este dato, de allí que hay que hacer cálculos.

Primero veamos como calcular la fecha de cumpleaños de **este** año.

Si nos propusiéramos hacer esto *a mano*, partiendo de la fecha de nacimiento y utilizando aritmética, encontraremos que necesitamos mantener día y mes, pero que el año sea el año actual. En otras palabras, al año de nacimiento debemos sumarle un número tal que el resultado de esa suma sea el año actual.

Ese número no es más que la diferencia entre el año actual y el año de nacimiento.

Podemos valernos de la función [`year()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql) para obtener el año de una fecha, y para obtener la diferencia, directamente de la resta de los años.

Finalmente, de la función [`dateadd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql) para agregar un número de años a una fecha.

Veamos en código:

```
select   year(getdate()) AnioActual
       , year('19750728') as AnioNacimiento
       , year(getdate()) - year('19750728') AniosHastaAnioActual
       , dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year('19750728'), '19750728') CumpleañosEsteAnio
```

```
AnioActual  AnioNacimiento AniosHastaAnioActual CumpleañosEsteAnio
----------- -------------- -------------------- -----------------------
2023        1975           48                   2023-07-28 00:00:00.000
```

De aquí, calcular el cumpleaños del próximo año resulta trivial, solamente hay que sumar uno a ese número de años:

```
select dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year('19750728') + 1, '19750728') CumpleañosPróximoAnio
```

```
CumpleañosPróximoAnio
-----------------------
2024-07-28 00:00:00.000
```

Finalmente, el próximo cumpleaños no es más que el cumpleaños de este año si no ha cumplido años y el del próximo si ya los cumplió. Dado que se espera el número de días para el próximo cumpleaños, queda definir qué hacer el día que cumple años. Para simplicidad de la respuesta, dejaremos que la consulta devuelva 0 días, es decir, que el día que cumple años, aún tomaremos como *próximo cumpleaños* el de este mismo año.

**Advertencia**: Quizás te parezca demasiado complicado hacerlo de esta manera, sé que al inicio suena mucho más sencillo convertir la fecha a una cadena y *sustituir* la parte del año. Eso funcionaría si no existieran los años bisiestos, pero existen y es una *solución* poco robusta si no los considera, o más complicada que la propuesta, si lo hace.

## Calcular la diferencia de días entre 2 fechas

La pieza final del rompecabezas es poder calcular la cantidad de días que deben transcurrir entre dos fechas. SQL Server nos da soporte para este cálculo en la función [`datediff()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql), pasándole el intervalo `day`.

```
select datediff(day, getdate(), '20230728') DíasCumpleaños2023
```

Devolverá la cantidad de días que faltan para mi cumpleaños este 2023. Si ya ha pasado mi cumpleaños del 2023, la función devolverá un número negativo que representa los días que han pasado desde mi cumpleaños del 2023.

## La solución final

Poniendo todas las piezas en su lugar, si has leído y comprendido los ejemplos, considero que el código se auto-explica.

Solo ten en cuenta que estoy haciendo el cálculo de la fecha del siguiente cumpleaños dentro de un [cross apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql). Esto permite que el código sea más legible, podríamos obtener un resultado similar con un CTE.

```
select   Nombres
       , Apellidos
       , cumple.FechaSiguienteCumple
       , datediff(day, getdate(), cumple.FechaSiguienteCumple) DiasParaSiguienteCumpleaños
  FROM Empleado
       cross apply (select case 
                             when month(Empleado.FechaNacimiento) * 100 + day(Empleado.FechaNacimiento) >= month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate()) then
                               dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(Empleado.fechanacimiento), Empleado.fechanacimiento)
                             else 
                               dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(Empleado.fechanacimiento) + 1, Empleado.fechanacimiento)
                           end FechaSiguienteCumple
                   ) cumple
```

Da un resultado como el siguiente:

```
Nombres Apellidos FechaSiguienteCumple DiasParaSiguienteCumpleaños
------- --------- -------------------- ---------------------------
Juan    Pérez     2024-05-01           363
Mario   López     2023-05-15           11
Josefa  López     2023-05-04           0
María   Pérez     2024-01-15           256
Pedro   Márquez   2023-12-01           211

(5 rows affected)
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar la función `DATEDIFF()` para obtener la diferencia en días entre la fecha actual y la fecha de cumpleaños de la persona. La función `DATEADD()` se utiliza para obtener la fecha de cumpleaños de la persona en el año actual.

Y en el `WHERE` puedes usar la función `MONTH()` para seleccionar solo los registros cuyo mes de cumpleaños coincide con este mes.

```
SELECT 
  Nombres,
  Apellidos,
  DATENAME(MONTH, Empleados.fechanacimiento) AS Mes, 
  DAY(Empleados.fechanacimiento) AS Dia,
  DATEDIFF(
    DAY, 
    GETDATE(), 
    DATEADD(
        YEAR, 
        YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(Empleados.fechanacimiento),
        Empleados.fechanacimiento
    )
   ) AS DiasRestantesCumple
FROM Empleados
WHERE 
  MONTH(Empleados.fechanacimiento) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Probé la consulta y me devuelve algunos registros con la cantidad de días en negativo.